# Beanbinding vetoableChangeSupport addVetoableChangeListener

Tags: java, beans-binding

Any one can tell what vetoableChangeSupport.addVetoableChangeListener is. I found this in Beansbinding. What vetoableChangeSupport.addVetoableChangeListener is for and its uses.Also you can go [here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport/addVetoableChangeListener%28VetoableChangeListener%20listener%29.html). How can we get make use of it in beansbinding and application developing? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc:

> You can register a VetoableChangeListener with a source bean so as to be notified of any constrained property updates.

And from the JavaDoc on the `vetoableChange(...)` method:

> PropertyVetoException - if the recipient wishes the property change to be rolled back.

This indicates you use the `VetoableChangeListener` to listen for property changes and if a change would violate a constraint you impose through that listener, it throws a `PropertyVetoException` which should cause the change to be rolled back.

Here's the JavaDoc for `VetoableChangeSupport` which includes examples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport.html

Comment: is there a difference/s between firepropertychangeListener?

Comment: @Aash please read the JavaDoc on those classes and methods. If you mean the `firePropertyChange()` method - well the difference is that the listeners informed by that method can't veto (cause a rollback of) the change, i.e. they are just informed, that's it.